# Matplotlib: What does calling plot function with an array do?

Tags: python, matplotlib

What does calling plot function with an array for both x and y do? Look at line number 15.

```
x1 = stats.norm.ppf(0.001)
x2 = stats.norm.ppf(0.999)

x = np.linspace(x1, x2, 100)

y = stats.norm.pdf(x)

yhalf = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if i > len(x)/2:
        yhalf.append(y[i])
    else:
        yhalf.append(0)

plt.plot([x, x], [y, yhalf], 'y-')

plt.axes().set_xlim(x1, x2)
```

[image: Plot]

Does it fill the area between two curves? Can we control or style this filling? I would like to fill with a smooth color with transparency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

> If x and/or y is 2-dimensional, then the corresponding columns will be plotted.

That is, if we have `a, b, c, d` all `np.array`s with the same size `s`, the command `plt.plot([a, b], [c, d])` will plot `s` number of lines `(a[0], c[0]) -> (b[0], d[0])`.

In your case `yhalf[0:len(x)/2]` is 0, and the other values are the same as `y`. From what I said before, you draw lines from `(x[i], y[i]) -> (x[i], yhalf[i])`, which for

```
case 1: i <  len(x)/2: (x[i], y[i]) -> (x[i], 0)    <-- the columns you see
case 2: i >= len(x)/2: (x[i], y[i]) -> (x[i], y[i]) <-- lines with 0 length (== invisible)
```

---

If you want to fill the area between two curves, try [`fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between). If I remember correct, you should be able to use it as

```
plt.fill_between([x, y], [x, yhalf])
```